# Browserify and bower. Canonical approach

Tags: node.js, bower, browserify

The way I'm using packages that not available out of the box in npm, right now  is like that:

package.json has:

```
 "napa": {
     "angular": "angular/bower-angular",
     "angular-animate": "angular/bower-angular-animate",
     "d3": "mbostock/d3",
     "ui-router":"angular-ui/ui-router",
     "bootstrap":"twbs/bootstrap"
  },
  "scripts": {
     "install": "node node_modules/napa/bin/napa"
```

and that installs files into node_modules directory, and I use them natively like this

```
require('angular/angular')
require('ui-router') 
... etc
```

That works, but I was thinking if it's possible to use packages installed with bower (into bower specific folder) and use them natively as node modules? Is it possible to tweak node's module resolution and force it to look for modules not just inside node_modules directory, but also in bower directory as well? Or maybe using `npm link` or whatever?

Is there some sort of convention to use browserify with bower?

Comment: Why would you use angular on the server? Or do those requires appear in the browser?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [browserify-shim](https://www.npmjs.org/package/browserify-shim) and configure the bower-installed modules in your `package.json` like this:

```
"browser": {
  "angular": "./bower_components/angular/angular.js",
  "angular-resource": "./bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"
},
"browserify-shim": {
  "angular": {
    "exports": "angular"
  },
  "angular-resource": {
    "depends": ["./bower_components/angular/angular.js:angular"]
  }
},
```

Then your code can `require` them by their short name as if there were regular npm modules.

[Here is the spec for the "browser" package.json property](https://gist.github.com/defunctzombie/4339901).

Comment: seems just setting everything in "browser" section works (even without installing browserify-shim)... Now the question: does browserify support wildcards in browser section? can we do: "browser":{"*":"./bower_components/"}. Or every single package has to be explicitly listed?

Comment: Wildcard support seems highly unlikely to me, but try it out.

Answer (score 41):

You can try to install via [debowerify](https://github.com/eugeneware/debowerify)

The package.json may then look as follows:

```
{
  "name": "browserify-begin",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "debowerify"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^4.1.5",
    "debowerify": "^0.7.1",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5"
  }
}
```

Given angular is installed with

```
bower install angular
```

Then within the js file will be as follows:

```
require("angular");
```