# Browserify overrides its own configuration when browsing a folder that contains a package.json?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browserify

I've created a simple JavaScript application using **AngularJS**.

I'm using **npm** and **Bower** to manage my dependencies, **Gulp** to automatise my tasks and I want to use the **CommonJS**' `module.exports`/`require()` to tie everything up together: I decided to go for **Browserify** to bundle this all up.

There's [my *very empty* and *clean* project on Github](https://github.com/ccjmne/angular-seed/tree/db5242724b1f8f18db32cecd695281301d21e8fa), if you wanna take a look.

---

In order to be able to `require('angular')`, I configured **Browserify** to shim that *AngularJS* into the available modules, using **browserify-shim**. Pretty straightforward, here's the relevant part of my `package.json`:

```
"browser": {
  "angular": "./bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"
},
"browserify": {
  "transform": [
    "browserify-shim"
  ]
},
"browserify-shim": {
  "angular": {
    "exports": "angular"
  }
}
```

It's pretty neat, my main JS file now looks like this:

```
'use strict';

var angular = require('angular');

angular.module('MyApp', [])
  .controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope', require('./view1/view1.js')])
  .controller('View2Ctrl', ['$scope', require('./view2/view2.js')]);
```

And that works.

---

Now, I'm trying to get into some more advanced stuff, using external libraries available through **Bower**. They get installed under `bower_components` and look -well- just like my project, they've got a `package.json`, a `bower.json` and all.

Take for example **ng-dialog**, which **also `require('angular')`**. Once retrieved via `bower install ng-dialog --save`, I do two things:

1. Link their dist's JS file to a keyword (let's say `ng-dialog`) in my `package.json`
2. `require('ng-dialog')` in main main JS file in order to have my Angular module depend on theirs.

Here's the updated relevant part of my `package.json` (note that **ng-dialog** does **not** need to be shimmed):

```
"browser": {
  "angular": "./bower_components/angular/angular.min.js",
  "ng-dialog": "./bower_components/ng-dialog/js/ngDialog.min.js"
},
"browserify": {
  "transform": [
    "browserify-shim"
  ]
},
"browserify-shim": {
  "angular": {
    "exports": "angular"
  }
}
```

... and my updated `app.js` file:

```
'use strict';

var angular = require('angular');
require('ng-dialog');

angular.module('MyApp', ['ngDialog'])
  .controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope', require('./view1/view1.js')])
  .controller('View2Ctrl', ['$scope', require('./view2/view2.js')]);
```

I get the following error while **Browserify-ing** this up:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'angular' from 'C:\...\bower_components\ng-dialog\js'
```

After a good half hour of tweaking around, it turned out that SIMPLY **deleting** the `package.json` file from `bower_components/ng-dialog` makes it all go smoothly.

What is going on and how the hell should I bundle that `ngDialog.min.js`?

Comment: Did you try debowerify approach from [Browserify and bower. Canonical approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691795/browserify-and-bower-canonical-approach)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the [Browserify Handbook](https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook)

> The module system that browserify uses is the same as node, so packages published to npm that were originally intended for use in node but not browsers will work just fine in the browser too.
>
> Increasingly, people are publishing modules to npm which are intentionally designed to work in both node and in the browser using browserify and many packages on npm are intended for use in just the browser. [npm is for all javascript](http://maxogden.com/node-packaged-modules.html), front or backend alike.

Therefore use the npm distribution of `Angular` and `ngDialog` packages rather than the bower ones

```
npm install angular ng-dialog --save
```

This will do away with the need to do the whole configuration in `package.json` and simply calling `require()` in the project will make browserify work.

When we require any node module in the project, browserify bundles the file present in the `main` field of the package.json of that respective node module. Currently as ngDialog's main field references the `ngDialog.js` file , therefore you will need to change it to `ngDialog.min.js` so that browserify bundles that file. (This isn't a major issue as you compress your browserify bundle using `gulp-uglify`)

I have forked your code and done the necessary changes in it - Check them here https://github.com/pra85/angular-seed

Comment: Thank you very, very much for this great answer!